# Edit database value when href is being clicked

Tags: php, sql, oop

I am trying to edit a value in my database after a href is being clicked and trying to achieve this by PHP, OOP/DPO without sql insertion.

```
<a href="#" name="klaar">EDIT DATA</a>
```

---

```
    public function markAsDone($id) {

    if(isset($_GET["klaar"])) {

        $q = "UPDATE todo SET Klaar = 0 WHERE ItemId = ".$id." ";
        $query = $this->_db->prepare($q);
        $query->execute($q);
    }
```

Comment: PHP's `PDO` library supports prepared queries, check out this tutorial: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Also any requests that modify data should be using the HTTP `POST` verb, see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

Comment: How are you calling your `markAsDone()` function? Just an `href` won't suffice. Plus, you're best using a POST method, why the GET?

Comment: I'm kind of new to PHP, so i actually wondered if it could be an option to call the markAsDone function in my href...

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to submit your form using

try this:

```
<form name="myform" action="handle-data.php">
Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
<a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: got it. You can use like this: <a href="yourpage.php?klaar=1" name="klaar">EDIT DATA</a>. Use like parameter. regards

Comment: I'm still getting an SQL injection, thanks for taking the time though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way:

The `?klaar` in the `href` will call your present file used, then call the function or execute something.

For example:

```
<a href="?klaar" name="klaar">EDIT DATA</a>

<?php

if(isset($_GET["klaar"])) {
echo getit(); // call the function
}

function getit(){
echo "It worked";
}
?>
```

You can modify it to suit.

---

Which in your case would look something like this:

```
public function markAsDone($id) {

    if(isset($_GET["klaar"])) {

    $q = "UPDATE todo SET Klaar = 0 WHERE ItemId = ".$id." ";
    $query = $this->_db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute($q);
    }
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_GET["klaar"])) {

    public function markAsDone($id) {

    $q = "UPDATE todo SET Klaar = 0 WHERE ItemId = ".$id." ";
    $query = $this->_db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute($q);
    }
}
```

Test it out. If you have any problems, let me know.